# creating 2 database at the same time in db2

Tags: linux, db2

Do you know whether it is safe to have in one shell user `db2inst1` creating a database A  and having another shell the same user creating at the same time database B?

```
create database A # shell 1
create database B # shell 2
```

I am using Linux/ Cent os with DB2 V 9.7 installed.

Comment: Do you have some reason to suspect it would not work?

Comment: Well. ye as I found some in the NODE000 some folder called  db2event and in it I found db2detaildeadlock.

Comment: I am not aware of any issues with this.

Comment: The `db2detaildeadlock` directory corresponds to the `DB2DETAILDEADLOCK` event monitor that is automatically created in all DB2 9.7 and earlier databases.  Nothing to worry about with this.

Comment: hi Ian. That's correct, I am working with 9.7 and thanks for this. At the end the 2 db were created successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also not quite sure why you are posting this without just attempting it, but yes, this will work without problem.

The only issues you might have are:

1. If the `NUMDB` database manager configuration parameter is small enough that you can't activate both databases at the same time (in addition to whatever other databases are activated within the DB2 instance).
2. If you use the `AUTOCONFIGURE` option for `CREATE DATABASE` with some silly default values so you exhaust system memory
3. System resource contention (disk, CPU) slowing the process down.

This is really an odd question – it's hard to image a scenario where you would *need* to create multiple databases simultaneously.  Are you coming from a different DBMS (like MySQL or SQL Server), where the concept of a database is more like a schema in DB2?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for getting back to my question. I did try to do that. The operation took quite some time. Usually on a small PC for 1 db takes me 20 minutes while on a server it takes not even a minute. The day I tried that operation it took me few hours. At the end of the day the db were created but it was very slow. BTW I need to thank you for your response that I like a lot.

Comment: Keep in mind that a PC will generally have less memory, and much slower disk(s) than a large server.  So your findings aren't necessarily surprising.  If this answers your question, please accept the answer.